# What are common ways to identify subject and object from a question?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I am looking for a way to extract the potential  subject and object from a question in **French**.

For the moment, I am building some handmade rules.
Alternatively, I started to think of using an already trained model for the task.
I wanted to use StanfordNLP parser but unfortunately it is not free for commercial use.

So, here comes the questions:

1. Are they ML models used for this task?
2. Are they labeled data sets (in french) which can help create ML models used for this task?

[Edit] I am looking mainly for open source tools/ libraries.

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297399/subject-object-identification-in-python? I would try the same thing for French. Spacy has support for French as well https://spacy.io/usage/models. I'd recommend the "fr_core_news_md" mode rather the small model.

Comment: I don't think that spacy's parser can be used for french :  https://spacy.io/api/annotation#section-dependency-parsing

Comment: Consider also using Google's [Cloud Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/). For testing use the text box under *Try the API*. For example, I tried "Qu'est-ce qu'il lui fait?" and the Syntax analysis resulted in telling me that "qu'" is dobj, "il" is nsubj, and "lui" is nobj. I do not speak French so I can't help you further with this :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am looking for open source libraries.

Comment: Did you check for dependency parsing?

Comment: Yes. This was my starting point. Since I didn't find any French dependency parser, I started looking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Google SyntaxNe has pre-trained models for French.  It is open source and can be customized for a specific use-case.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/syntaxnet/g3doc/universal.md

With this, you can create a dependency tree for questions and evaluate fitness for this application.

Comment: Does it support python or is it only usable via command lines?

Comment: Command line examples are for demo, it is meant to be used from Python or other languages that interface with Tensorflow.